# Change string indexes to be ObjectID ones in large MongoDB instance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, high-load

So, I've git a large production database dump with `_id` field as `strings`. Different collections got those string's length different. There're a lot of relations there. I need a way to change string `_ids` to `ObjectId` ones.

What I've tried already:

1) Looking mongoose/mongodb documentation for single command to do that failed

2) node.js migration script that grabs all the entries in one collection and wraps `string` id into `ObjectId` just fails either because of stack overflow `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory` if we're trying to delete-and-recreate approach or with an error about bad string lenght and impossibility to create `ObjectId` from that string.

Will attach data samples and/or mongoose schema a bit later.

Comment: Do you need to preserve the existing ids? Or new one can be recreated? (BTW the `JavaScript heap out of memory` is likely due to a non limited or serialized find(), you could just use a cursor to solve this)

Comment: @DBellavista I'll be fine with recreating ids as far as all relations will persist. As I can see, we stick to an id recreation because string indexes have different length between collections.
Talking about `heap out of memory`, may you share a cursor bust example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and inefficient cursor solution to avoid JavaScript heap out of memory is to serialize everytyhing. Of course in order to edit the `_id` you have to create a new document and remove the old one.

```
const cursor = Model.find().lean().cursor();
let doc;
while ((doc = await cursor.next())) {
  // The string must be a valid ObjectId, otherwhise it won't work
  if (typeof doc._id === 'string') {
    let newId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(doc._id);
    let newDoc = new Model(Object.assign({}, doc, {_id: newId}));
    await newDoc.save();
    await Model.remove({_id: doc._id});
  }
}
```

However, if you have errors about incorrect ids, it may be beacause the string id are not actually stringified version of mongo ObjectId. In such case, the relation cannot be preserved.